# object datasource returns 0 and empty values using get; set; database mapping C# while using dapper orm

Tags: c#, dapper

> I'm trying to retrieve data from SQL server into a gridView Control, but however get 0 values in my first column and an empty column in my second column. My mapping class to get data from sql server:

```
    public class classInvoiceNumberSQL
{
    public  int RowNumber { get; set; }
    public int invoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public double InvoiceTotal { get; set; }
}
```

> And this part is where i execute to pull through the data from sql

```
        private void btnLoadByDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Invo_X.P.Properties.Settings.conSQL"].ConnectionString))
        {
            if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                db.Open();
                string query = "Select RowLines, invoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, CustomerID, invoiceTotal From tblInvoiceNumber";
                classInvoiceNumberSQLBindingSource.DataSource = db.Query<classInvoiceNumberSQL>(query, commandType: CommandType.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

> Here an overview of whats happening when i run the project.
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVdJW.png)

And the data which is in sql server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMh4Y.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping is wrong. You have RowLines in your database, but RowNumber in your DTO.

Declare it like this:

```
public class classInvoiceNumberSQL
{
    public  int RowLines { get; set; }
    public int invoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }        
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public double InvoiceTotal { get; set; }
}
```